# Display the word "Today" instead of data format in Datatable.js table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, momentjs

I would like to display the word "Today" instead of, for example, "Mon 16 Aug 2021" in my Datatable.js table.

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mauricetwomey/nsbk7Lry/62/

I would like the result to display "Today" wherever today's date is in the table:

[image: datatable]

I am using moment.js to handle the date formatting but I cannot get the locale feature to automatically change a date format to a string.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('ddd D MMM YYYY');
    var table = $("#orders").DataTable({
        columns: [
            { orderable: !1 },
            { orderable: !0 },
            { orderable: !1 },
            { orderable: !1 },
            { orderable: !1 },
        ],
        order: [[1, "desc"]],
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably ultra stupid, but can't you just run a replace function once everything is done and replace "Today's string" with "Today" literally? This could be slow if you have millions of rows but I don't think your data table is that big. Of course, do test this smooth-brain-function in various scenarios (changing page, doing some submit, etc.)

To be honest I'd rather just make it bold maybe, or use color (maybe). IF people deem that useful.

Comment: @Apache Datatables is powerful, there're dozens of native functions available to do anything and everything. One should always look for these native functions rather than tricks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using [`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell)

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "targets": [1,3],
  "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
    if (moment(cellData).isSame(moment(), "day")) {
      $(td).html('Today')
    }
  }
}]
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mauricetwomey/nsbk7Lry/69/